# Java - java.lang.IllegalStateException: source already consumed or closed

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have some code:

```
    Stream<String> previewImagesURLsList = uploadedVideoItemObj.getPreviewImagesURLsList().parallel();

    Stream<HashMap<String, Object>> imagesStream = previewImagesURLsList
            .map(new Function<String, HashMap<String, Object>>() {
                @Override
                public HashMap<String, Object> apply(String fileName) {
                    HashMap<String, Object> m = new HashMap<>();
                    m.put("preview_file", fileName);
                    m.put("parent_id", gotId);
                    return m;
                }
            });

    HashMap<String, Object>[] filesArr = imagesStream.toArray(HashMap[]::new);
```

I got on line

```
 HashMap<String, Object>[] filesArr = imagesStream.toArray(HashMap[]::new);
```

an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: source already consumed or closed
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.sourceSpliterator(AbstractPipeline.java:455)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:255)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:438)
    at my.site.objects.videoitems.uploadedVideoItems.dao.impl.JdbcUploadedVideoItemDAO.insert(JdbcUploadedVideoItemDAO.java:79)
    at my.site.processors.files.threads.ServerUploadedFileProcessor.processFileServer(ServerUploadedFileProcessor.java:53)
    at my.site.processors.files.threads.ServerUploadedFileProcessor.call(ServerUploadedFileProcessor.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I can't understand, where is bug. What means this exception and in what cases in can be throwed?

Comment: In your first line isn't it `.parallelStream();`?

Comment: Yes, first stream - is parallel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems your `getPreviewImagesURLsList()` is returning a `Stream` despite its name. A `Stream` can be used only once so you must ensure that each invocation of `getPreviewImagesURLsList()` returns a new `Stream`.

Or better, let it return `List` as its name suggests and let the caller invoke `stream()` on it.

By the way, the usual way of using `Stream`s is to chain the method invocations rather than storing the intermediate results in variables to avoid erroneous multiple uses of these variables:

```
HashMap<String, Object>[] filesArr =
  uploadedVideoItemObj.getPreviewImagesURLsList().parallel()
  // or better if getPreviewImagesURLsList() was returning a List:
  // uploadedVideoItemObj.getPreviewImagesURLsList().parallelStream()
  .map(fileName -> {
    HashMap<String, Object> m = new HashMap<>();
    m.put("preview_file", fileName);
    m.put("parent_id", gotId);
    return m;
  }).toArray(HashMap[]::new);
```